# .net core 2.1 ocelot gateway returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gateway, ocelot

I am trying to implement the ocelot gateway in my application but it always returns 404 on all paths I configured in ocelot.json.

Whenever I make a GET on Postman using either the simple calls or the aggregate one it always returns 404 and the program keeps running, it does not crash.

Ocelot.json:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Buildings",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/allBuildings",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "Key": "Buildings"
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Device",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/allDevices",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "Key": "Devices"
    }
  ],
  "Aggregates": [
    {
      "ReRouteKeys": [
        "Buildings",
        "Devices"
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/BAD",
      "Aggregator":  "FakeDefinedAggregator"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:44351/"
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config
                        .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    s.AddOcelot();
                })
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseOcelot().Wait();
                })
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

         //   await app.UseOcelot();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
```

I am using .NET Core 2.1 and Ocelot NuGet package version 13.5.1 .

Comment: What exact path are you calling via postman?

Comment: Also, why are you using request aggregation?

Comment: The path for postman I use is: localhost:61234/BAD (61234 being the port for the gateway). I use request aggregation because I need the data from both and don't want to use two requests, mostly because the requests are in different microservices and these ones are in the same one, being used just as a test.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using request aggregation you need to register your IDefinedAggregator implementation with Ocelot.

Like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOcelot(Configuration).AddSingletonDefinedAggregator<FakeDefinedAggregator>();
}
```

otherwise Ocelot will not be able to find your aggregator in the container.

Comment: Where does it says it's a must?